# Git fetch command succeeds at command line but fails in bash script

Tags: git, bash, github

```
git fetch someremote  # the remote is on github.com, and using SSH
```

the above command succeeds if I issue it from a terminal, but if I put it in a bash script, it will fail, with:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I hope this gives someone some clue as to help figure out why it fails in the bash script but succeeds at a terminal! Anyone have any idea?

Same thing seems to happen if I use either SSH or HTTPS

Comment: Do you use an SSH agent? That would explain why you can connect to github over ssh after having entered your password, and cannot automate it.

Comment: Also, what user are you while calling the script? Your normal user or do you sudo the script?

Comment: @Vrakfall either sudo or no sudo, same thing

Comment: It's better not to sudo, in this case. :P Also, are you using a specific ssh agent, as @EricDuminil asked and/or a specific ssh key, aka other than `~/.ssh/id_rsa`?

Comment: No SSH agent to my knowledge, I set up SSH keys the standard way with Github using .ssh/id_rsa etc

Comment: The script and the command are running in the same terminal?

Comment: @Ivan yeah that's right, same terminal session

Comment: Does your script have some additional commands or just "git fetch"? May you create the new script with only "git fetch" command and run it? Maybe your shell is different with script shell?

Comment: Which shell do are you using? Do you have any special environment variables defined in your shell (e.g. zsh)?

Answer (score 2):

Probably a problem with your environment variables. Why not try `diff`ing them?

```
$ echo "printenv | sort > /tmp/script.env" > /tmp/envtest.sh
$ bash /tmp/envtest.sh
$ printenv | sort > /tmp/term.env
$ diff /tmp/term.env /tmp/script.env
```

In my terminal I get:

```
76c76
< SHLVL=1
---
> SHLVL=2
```